# How many Warframes and weapons can I store without spending Platinum?

Tags: warframe

What is the max amount of warframes and weapons can you have, without spending Platinum? I know that EXP is only earned from non-maxed out items, so I am building weapons and Warframes so I can start leveling again. What is the max amount I can have? I am overall rank 3.

Comment: I find your question a hard to understand, if my answer isn't what you are looking for please update your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Affinity is earned even with maxed out gear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't recall how many Warframe and weapon slots you start with (I've bought several expansions for each), but here's how you can check how many you have of each:

<sup>*edited for update 10 UI overhaul*</sup>
In the upper right, pick the Arsenal button. Then pick the Inventory button (right above mods). By default you should now be looking at your Warframes; it will list each Warframe you have, its rank, how much it sells for (almost always 10k credits), and also any empty Warframe slots you have. If you look in the upper left of this display, the next button to the right of the Warframe selection is weapons. If you pick that all of your weapons will be listed, along with their ranks & sell values. As with Warframes, if you scroll to the end of this list it will tell you how many empty slots you have.

I *think* you start with 2 Warframe slots and 6(?) weapon slots.

Comment: I started like week ago and I have 2 WF slots and 8 weapon slots(including the filled ones). And I haven't bought anything for plat yet so I guess it should be what u start with.

Answer (score 8):

There is no limit on how many frames or weapons you can have, but you will have to spend plat to get more room or sell old frames and weapons.

You can also have multiple of the same, but you only get Mastery Rank xp the first time you level a frame or weapon. Having multiple of the same weapon will not give you more Mastery Rank xp.

Currently there are 16 frames (14 normal and 2 prime) and about 89 weapons in game.

If you level them all you will reach rank 12 and be 6000 points in to the rank.

So in other words to reach rank 12 you either need all weapons and 15 frames or all frames and miss out on 2 weapons.

There are currently 4 weapons that are no longer available in game so you need to own 2 of those weapons to reach rank 12.
The weapons you can no longer get are Lato Vandal, Braton Vandal, Snipetron Vandal and Snipetron.

Comment: This is good information but doesn't really answer the question now that the OP has edited it.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to these answer, there were ways to increase your inventory slots without spending platinum.

When DE grants Event Weapons (anniversary, event, etc.), all weapons supplied will come their own Orokin Catalyst, complete with a Weapon Slot free of charge. This means that even if you sold the event weapons (don't know why you would), you'd have a nice extra slot to store your weapons. This means that these are essentially free slots.

So past events that have granted Weapons w/ weapon slots:

- Machete Wraith

  - Completing at least 25 missions during the [Gradivus Dilemna](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/The_Gradivus_Dilemma)
- Strun Wraith

  - Surviving at least 20 minutes during the [Survival Weekend Event](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Survival_Weekend_Event)
- Twin Wraith Vipers

  - Scoring 100 points during the [Cicero Crisis](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/The_Cicero_Crisis)
- Gorgon Wraith

  - Completing the mission with 500 points or more during [Tethra's Doom](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Tethra%27s_Doom)
- Prova Vandal

  - Scoring 48 points during the [Operation Breeding Grounds](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Operation_Breeding_Grounds)
- Brakk

  - Siding with the Grineer more than the Corpus during the [Gradvius Dilemna](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/The_Gradivus_Dilemma)
- Snipetron Vandal

  - 20 or more informer kills during the [Informant Event](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Informant_Event)
- Braton

  - With the purchase of the E3 Humble Bundle pack (technically not spending Platinum)

This means that if you were around since Warframe started, and did each event to receive the weapon rewards, you would have:

- 2 Warframe Slots
- 6 Weapon Slots
- 8 additional Weapon Slots

for a total of:

- 2 Warframe slots
- 14 Weapon slots